# GASでパラメータをオブジェクトの値にすると!=がおかしくなる？

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

お世話になります。
GASでWebアプリケーションを作成し、パラメーターをオブジェクトに格納してから、同じ値を持っている2つの要素を`!=`または`!==`で比較すると、真が返ってしまうという現象に悩まされています。
自分なりに簡単にまとめたコードは以下のようになります。

```
function doGet (e) {
  var parm = e.parameters;
  var foo = {};
  for (var key in parm) {
    foo[key] = parm[key];
  }
  Logger.log('foo.x:【' + foo.x + '】');
  Logger.log('foo.y:【' + foo.y + '】');
  Logger.log('x != y:' + (foo.x != foo.y));
  Logger.log('x !== y:' + (foo.x !== foo.y));
}
```

上のコードをWebアプリケーションとしてデプロイし、以下のURLにアクセスします。

> [https://script.google.com/a/組織名.example.com/macros/s/](https://script.google.com/a/%E7%B5%84%E7%B9%94%E5%90%8D.example.com/macros/s/){オブジェクトID}/exec?x=A&y=A

doGet()はHTMLを返していませんので、ブラウザーには以下のメッセージが表示されます。

> The script completed but did not return anything.

そして、スクリプトエディタでCtrl+Enterを押下してログを表示すると以下のようになります。

> [20-02-05 03:14:34:357 PST] foo.x:【A】 
>   [20-02-05 03:14:34:357 PST] foo.y:【A】
>   [20-02-05 03:14:34:358 PST] x != y:true
>   [20-02-05 03:14:34:359 PST] x !== y:true

`foo.x`も`foo.Y`もAという値を格納しているのに、なぜ`!=`および`!==`が真になるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あまり詳しくないのですが、`param[key]` を代入する代わりに `"A"` を代入しても同じ結果になりますか？　また、文字列として表示するのではなくバイト列として表示させても同じ値が入っているように見えるのでしょうか。

Comment: `?x=A&y=A`のクエリパラメータでWeb Appsへ値を送ると、`doGet(e)`の`e.parameters`は`{"x":["A"],"y":["A"]}`です。お使いのスクリプトの場合、`foo`は`{"x":["A"],"y":["A"]}`となり、`foo.x != foo.y`および`foo.x !== foo.y`は結果として両方ともに`true`が返されます。そこで、`e.parameters`の代わりに`e.parameter`にしてはいかがでしょうか。この場合、`e.parameter`は、`{"x":"A","y":"A"}`ですので、スクリプトは問題なく動作するように思われます。[Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメントをいただき、ありがとうございます。
自己回答の形でまとめさせていただきます。
質問のコードを以下のように改めて実行しました。

```
function doGet (e) {
  var parm = e.parameters;
  var foo = {};
  foo.v = 'B';
  foo.w = 'B';
  for (var key in parm) {
    foo[key] = parm[key];
  }
  for (var key in foo) {
    Logger.log('foo[' + key + ']:' + foo[key] + ' typeof(foo[key]):' + typeof(foo[key]));
  }
  Logger.log('foo.v:【' + foo.v + '】');
  Logger.log('foo.w:【' + foo.w + '】');
  Logger.log('foo.x:【' + foo.x + '】');
  Logger.log('foo.y:【' + foo.y + '】');
  Logger.log('v != w:' + (foo.v != foo.w));
  Logger.log('v !== w:' + (foo.v !== foo.w));
  Logger.log('x != y:' + (foo.x != foo.y));
  Logger.log('x !== y:' + (foo.x !== foo.y));
}
```

結果は以下のとおりです。

> [20-02-06 00:49:30:187 PST] foo[v]:B typeof(foo[key]):string [20-02-06
>   00:49:30:189 PST] foo[w]:B typeof(foo[key]):string [20-02-06
>   00:49:30:189 PST] foo[x]:A typeof(foo[key]):object [20-02-06
>   00:49:30:190 PST] foo[y]:A typeof(foo[key]):object [20-02-06
>   00:49:30:191 PST] foo.v:【B】 [20-02-06 00:49:30:191 PST] foo.w:【B】
>   [20-02-06 00:49:30:192 PST] foo.x:【A】 [20-02-06 00:49:30:192 PST]
>   foo.y:【A】 [20-02-06 00:49:30:193 PST] v != w:false [20-02-06
>   00:49:30:193 PST] v !== w:false [20-02-06 00:49:30:194 PST] x !=
>   y:true [20-02-06 00:49:30:195 PST] x !== y:true

以上のことから以下のことが分かりました。

- `foo[key] = 'STR'`という代入によって得られる`foo[key]`は文字列で値は`STR`
- WebAppを`?key=STR`というクエリーパラメーターとともに呼び出し、`doGet(e)`関数で受けて、`foo[key] = e.parameters[key]`という代入によって得られる`foo[key]`は配列で中身は`["STR"]`
- `foo[key_1] = 'STR_1'`、`foo[key_2] = 'STR_2'`を実行した場合`foo[key_1] != foo[key_2]`は`true`
- `foo[key_1] = ['STR_1']`で`foo[key_2] = ['STR_2']`の場合`foo[key_1] != foo[key_2]`は`false`

いっぽう、上記のコードの

```
  var parm = e.parameters;
```

を

```
  var parm = e.parameters;
```

と変更して実行すると、以下の結果が得られました。

> [20-02-06 01:01:52:327 PST] foo[v]:B typeof(foo[key]):string [20-02-06
>   01:01:52:327 PST] foo[w]:B typeof(foo[key]):string [20-02-06
>   01:01:52:328 PST] foo[x]:A typeof(foo[key]):string [20-02-06
>   01:01:52:329 PST] foo[y]:A typeof(foo[key]):string [20-02-06
>   01:01:52:329 PST] foo.v:【B】 [20-02-06 01:01:52:330 PST] foo.w:【B】
>   [20-02-06 01:01:52:331 PST] foo.x:【A】 [20-02-06 01:01:52:331 PST]
>   foo.y:【A】 [20-02-06 01:01:52:332 PST] v != w:false [20-02-06
>   01:01:52:333 PST] v !== w:false [20-02-06 01:01:52:333 PST] x !=
>   y:false [20-02-06 01:01:52:334 PST] x !== y:false

以上のことから、以下のことが分かりました。

- WebAppをクエリーパラメーター`?key=STR`とともに呼び出し、`doGet(e)`関数で受けて、`foo[key] = e.parameter[key]`という代入によって得られる`foo[key]`は文字列で中身は`"STR"`

要約すると、

- doGet(e)においてe.parametersは各クエリーパラメーターを配列で返す
- おなじくdoGet(e)においてe.parameterは各クエリーパラメーターを文字列で返す

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

- JavaScriptは同じ値を持つ2つの異なるオブジェクトを比較すると、!=も!==も常にtrueになる

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

クエリーパラメーターを複数得たいケースが現在開発中のシステムには存在しないので、`e.parameter()`を使用することで対応できそうです。

コメントありがとうございました！！